# AWS spare EC2 compute capacity, how it is calculated?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

**Spot Instance Definition:**
Spot Instances are spare EC2 compute capacity in the AWS Cloud available to you at savings of up to 90% off compared to On-Demand prices

**My Confusions are:**

1. How this Spare EC2 compute capacity is calculated
2. This Spare Capacity calculation is based on the Current Account OR Current Region OR Entire AWS Regions ?

Comment: AWS runs big datacenters of servers.  while you an aws customer gets to turn on and off virtual servers at will, AWS must have already provisioned servers in case somebody wants to use them.  That's where the extra capacity comes from - the servers that aren't currently being used for OnDemand (eg not Spot) instances.  capacity is per Availability zone, which corresponds to a logical datacenter (though not necessarily one physical location).  Like the underlying servers, extra capacity is not tied to a particular account.

Comment: If I just created an AWS account & assume that I am not creating any resources , then am I eligible for spot instance ? Or I need to create an EC2 on demand instance , and whenever not using it then only spare CPU time will add to my account to claim spot instance ?

Comment: whether you run any other resources is irrelevant.  spot instances are a way for amazon to monetize otherwise unused compute capacity.  spot instances are available to any user regardless of usage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anybody with an AWS Account can launch an Amazon EC2 instance as a Spot Instance. If there is **available capacity for the selected Instance Type and Availability Zone**, the Spot Instance will be launched and you will be charged a price that is at the current Spot Price (normally much less than On-Demand prices).

However, **AWS can stop/terminate that Spot Instance at any time** when they need the capacity for customers who are using On-Demand instances. Therefore, the Spot Instance is not guaranteed to keep running.

You have no visibility into the available capacity or the likelihood that the Spot Instance will be stopped/terminated. If you want to **maintain a level of capacity using Spot Instances**, then you can use a [Spot Fleet - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/spot-fleet.html), which can automatically replace Spot Instances when they are stopped/terminated.

Comment: spot instances have a reputation of being very unreliable, however the algorithms have changed in the not too distant past and they are more reliable now than in the past (https://www.levimccormick.com/2018/04/08/dr.-spotinstance/).  You get 2 minutes of warning when a spot instance is going to be terminated.

Comment: I presume that by "reliable", you mean the chance of the instance running for a long period (as opposed to the instance not providing dependable compute infrastructure).

Comment: yes, a better word might have been "available" (the note was of course for future readers, not you)